# Using database-first approach with string primary key and a one-to-many relationship not working in ASP.NET Core Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-core, ef-database-first

I have two model classes:

```
public partial class customer
{
    public string customer_id { get; set; }   // Primary Key
    public string customer_name { get; set; }
    public string course_mobile { get; set; }

    public  List<customer_address> customer_addresses { get; set; }
}

public partial class customer_address
{
    public string address_id { get; set; }    // Primary Key
    public string adreess { get; set; }
  
    public  customer customer { get; set; }
    public string customer_id { get; set; }   // Foreign Key
}
```

I get an error:

> The entity type 'customer' requires a primary key to be defined.

So how it solve?

[Datbase table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpCJJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `[Key]` attrubute.

```
public partial class customer
{
    [Key]
    public string customer_id { get; set; }   // Primary Key
    public string customer_name { get; set; }
    public string course_mobile { get; set; }

    public  List<customer_address> customer_addresses { get; set; }
}

public partial class customer_address
    {
        [Key]
        public string address_id { get; set; } // Primary Key
        public string adreess { get; set; }


        public customer customer { get; set; }
        
        public string customer_id { get; set; }  // Foriegn Key
    }
```

Comment: In both models add [Key] attribute
error:  Invalid object name 'customers'.

In DB context define customers

   public DbSet<customer> customers { get; set; }

   public DbSet<customer_address> customer_Addresses { get; set; }

Comment: I have edited my answer. you can remove-migration and try again

Comment: I have both tables already. plz, solve using DB first approach... you given solution 

 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                modelBuilder.Entity<customer_address>()
                    .HasOne(p => p.customer)
                    .WithMany(b => b.customer_addresses)
                    .HasForeignKey(p => p.customer_id);
            }

not working.. same error invalid objrect name 'customers'.

Comment: I am very sorry for ignoring you are using `DB first`, After you add [`Key]` attribute, The error message is `Invalid object name 'customers'`, I suggest you to check if the name of database in `ConnectionStrings` has been configured correctly

Comment: ConnectionStrings is correct and run other modules perfectly. But not this I have share Modes, Repository, Dbcontext ,interface
models are the same as we post previously 
**Repository:**
public async Task<List<customer>> GetAllCustomer()
        {
              var records = await _context.customers.Include(c => c.customer_addresses)             
                                   .ToListAsync();
            return records;
        }
**DbContext:**
 public DbSet<customer> customers { get; set; }
 public DbSet<customer_address> customer_Addresses { get; set; }

Comment: **ICustomer**     ------ Interface
Task<List<customer>> GetAllCustomer();
Task<customer> GetCustomerById(string customer_id);
**Controller:**
        [HttpGet("")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllCustomer()
        {
            var customer= await _customer.GetAllCustomer();
            return Ok(customer);
        }
**Startup.cs**
services.AddTransient<ICustomer, CustomerRepository>();
thses are full code related to customer module... may be help you to understand my issue

Comment: Hi@Santosh Vishwakarma, you need to provide your database design in your question. Where do you  get the `The entity type 'customer' requires a primary key to be defined.` error? You can use this command to automatically generate the corresponding model in Package Manager Console `Scaffold-DbContext "Your ConnectionStrings" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models`

Comment: Hi @Xinran Shen I have share the database table structure

Comment: Hi@Santosh Vishwakarma, you already have a database, So you can follow the steps below. First , add `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` and `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` Nuget Package. Second, Use this command in Package Manager Console `Scaffold-DbContext "Server=xxxxxxx;Database=xxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models`. Then The project will automatically generate models and Dbcontext files